# Why doesn't my VBScript string concatenation work?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I've written a VBScript script for file download. I use this line to build the download URL:

```
strURL = DownloadDest & pdfs(n)
```

But when I run the script, `strURL` gets just the `DownloadDest` value without `pdfs(n)`. Why doesn't string concatenation work?

Complete script:

```
dim pdfs(9)
pdfs(1) = "Karusel_PF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(2) = "Karusel_ZCHF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(3) = "Karusel_YF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(4) = "karusel_Moscow_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(5) = "Karusel_SVF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(6) = "Karusel_VVF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(7) = "Karusel_SZF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(8) = "Karusel_SOCHI_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(9) = "Karusel_VLGRD_promo18_food.pdf"



Const scriptVer  = "1.0"
const DownloadDest = "http://karusel.ru/manager/img/PDF/"
Const LocalFile = "C:\Users\syurchen\Desktop\"
Const DownloadType = "binary"
dim strURL 
dim localfile2 

function getit(n)
  dim xmlhttp

  set xmlhttp = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

  strURL = DownloadDest & pdfs(n)
  localfile2 = LocalFile & pdfs(n)
  msgbox "Download-URL: " & strURL

  xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false

  xmlhttp.Send
  Wscript.Echo "Download-Status: " & xmlhttp.Status & " " & xmlhttp.statusText

  If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
    Dim objStream
    set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
    objStream.SaveToFile localFile2
    objStream.Close
    set objStream = Nothing
  End If

  set xmlhttp = Nothing
End function 

For Each n In pdfs
  getit(n)
Next
```

Comment: I took the liberty to reword your question to make the problem description clear to other readers. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

VBScript array indexes start from 0. `dim pdfs(9)` creates an array with 10 (not 9) elements, but you don't specify the 0th element so it's `Empty` by default. That's why on the first iteration `pdf(n)` is `Empty` instead of containing the file path.

You need to change your code to:

```
dim pdfs(8)
pdfs(0) = "Karusel_PF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(1) = "Karusel_ZCHF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(2) = "Karusel_YF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(3) = "karusel_Moscow_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(4) = "Karusel_SVF_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(5) = "Karusel_VVF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(6) = "Karusel_SZF_Promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(7) = "Karusel_SOCHI_promo18_food.pdf"
pdfs(8) = "Karusel_VLGRD_promo18_food.pdf"
```

Or don't use hard-coded indexes:

```
Dim pdfs
pdfs = Array ( _
    "Karusel_PF_Promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_ZCHF_promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_YF_promo18_food.pdf", _
    "karusel_Moscow_promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_SVF_promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_VVF_Promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_SZF_Promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_SOCHI_promo18_food.pdf", _
    "Karusel_VLGRD_promo18_food.pdf" _
)
```

Other tips:

1. If you save the file to your Desktop (not another user's), don't hard-code the Desktop folder path. Use [`SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe(v=vs.84).aspx) to get it:

   ```
   Dim oShell, strDesktop
   oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   strDesktop = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
   ...
   localfile2 = strDesktop & pdfs(n)
   ```
2. The `strURL` and `localfile2` variables are used only inside the `getit` function, so it's better to `Dim` them in that function.
3. The `scriptVer` and `DownloadType` constants aren't used and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

you use a `for each` to iterate through `pdfs`:

```
For Each n In pdfs
  getit(n)
Next
```

So `n` is a string from the `pdfs` array, but inside `getit` you use `n` as an array index:

```
strURL = DownloadDest & pdfs(n)
```

That's a type mismatch error. Your `for each` has already extracted the string from the array so you just need to use it like this inside `getit`:

```
strURL = DownloadDest & n
```